# Given string s, find the shortest string t, such that, t^m=s

Tags: string, algorithm

Given string s, find the shortest string t, such that, t^m=s.

Examples:

```
s="aabbb" => t="aabbb"
s="abab"  => t = "ab"
```

How fast can it be done?

Of course naively, for every m divides |s|, I can try if substring(s,0,|s|/m)^m = s.

One can figure out the solution in O(d(|s|)n) time, where d(x) is the number of divisors of s. Can it be done more efficiently?

Answer (score 5):

This is the problem of computing the period of a string. [Knuth, Morris and Pratt's sequential string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) is a good place to get started. This is in a paper entitled "Fast Pattern Matching in Strings" from 1977.

If you want to get fancy with it, then check out the paper "Finding All Periods and Initial Palindromes of a String in Parallel" by Breslauer and Galil in 1991. From their abstract:

> An optimal O(log log n) time CRCW-PRAM algorithm for computing all
>   periods of a string is presented. Previous parallel algorithms compute
>   the period only if it is shorter than half of the length of the
>   string. This algorithm can be used to find all initial palindromes of
>   a string in the same time and processor bounds. Both algorithms are
>   the fastest possible over a general alphabet. We derive a lower bound
>   for finding palindromes by a modification of a previously known lower
>   bound for finding the period of a string [3]. When p processors are
>   available the bounds become \Theta(d n p e + log log d1+p=ne 2p).

Answer (score 4):

I really like this thing called the z-algorithm: http://www.utdallas.edu/~besp/demo/John2010/z-algorithm.htm

For every position it calculates the longest substring starting from there, that is also a prefix of the whole string. (in linear time of course).

```
a   a   b   c   a   a   b   x   a   a   a   z
    1   0   0   3   1   0   0   2   2   1   0
```

Given this "z-table" it is easy to find all strings that can be exponentiated to the whole thing. Just check for all positions if `pos+z[pos] = n`.

In our case:

```
a   b   a   b
    0   2   0
```

Here `pos = 2` gives you `2+z[2] = 4 = n` hence the shortest string you can use is the one of length 2.

This will even allow you to find cases where only a prefix of the exponentiated string matches, like:

```
a   b   c   a
    0   0   1
```

Here `(abc)^2` can be cut down to your original string. But of course, if you don't want matches like this, just go over the divisors only.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it in `O(|s|)` time.

You can search for a "target" string of length `n` in a "source" string of length `m` in `O(n+m)` time. Build a solution based on that.

Let both source and target be `s`. An additional constraint is that 1 and any positions in the source that do not divide `|s|` are not valid starting positions for the match. Of course the search per se will always fail. But if there's a partial match and you have reached the end of the sourse string, then you have a solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

a modification to Boyer-Moore could possibly handle this in O(n) where n is length of s

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm