# How to find the number of the lexicographically minimal string rotation?

Tags: string, algorithm, circular-buffer

How to find the number of [lexicographically minimal string rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation)?

For example:

```
S = abab, N = 2
S = abca, N = 1
S = aaaa, N = 4
```

I tried Duval's algorithm, it works very long. The string length of 100000000 characters.

Comment: I don't think you want lexicographically minimal string rotation, but the period of a periodic string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347812/given-string-s-find-the-shortest-string-t-such-that-tm-s

Comment: What do you mean by number of rotation? Does each rotation have a number? What is the number of a rotation? Don't you rather want the total number of rotations (rotationS - in **plural**)?

Comment: **Duval's algorithm works in `O(N)` with `O(1)` memory requirement. If this seems to be slow to you, give it up, there won't be anything faster!** The program needs at least to read the whole string, which gives the minimum time `O(N)`!

Comment: What do you call very long ? How did you implement it ? Using what language ? Properly coded and optimized, a linear-time algorithm on 10^8 elements should take a few seconds.

Comment: @Tomas O(N) does not mean that there is nothing that could be faster. There could be an another algorithm with O(N) complexity, and 100x faster execution time.

Comment: @kupsef only by a constant :) Yes of course I know. The problem of the OP is that he puts *huge* amount of data into fast algorithm and he just says *"it's slow"*. What can you say to him :)

Comment: @Tomas Only the constant what matters in practise, when you compare two algorithm with same complexity:) I know the huge dataset is the problem, I just wanted to point that out O(N) does not mean "fastest":)

Comment: @kupsef your comment is only theoretic though. In this case there is really hardly any chance that the OP will find anything faster than the Duval.

Comment: @Tomas You misunderstand me, I just wanted to point out your incorrect deduction : O(N) --> fastest

Comment: @Tomas I understood you very well but this is only theoretic discussion, as I wrote in my previous comment - not very relevant for OPs case. Look we just cluttered this question with 6 comments about some theoretic discussion, I suggest we do a comment cleanup and delete these comments.

Answer (score 4):

Easy -- just determine the minimum period of the string. A string which is periodic in minimal period `K` will produce identical (and hence lexicographically equal) strings for exactly `N/K` different rotations, so whatever the lexicographic minimum is, it'll be the result of `N/K` different rotations.

Comment: I tried Duval's algorithm, it works very long. The string length of 100000000 characters.

Comment: Why would you need Duval's algorithm? Nothing about determining the *number* of least permutations requires you to find *any* of them.

Comment: Then how can I find `K`?

Comment: @user3164559: Well, you said N = 100000000 = 10^8. K must be a divisor of N. N = 10^8 = 2^8 * 5^8 has only 9*9 = 81 divisors. Not counting N itself leaves us with 80 possibilities. So why not simply verify all 80 possible rotations? It should be straightforward to validate each possibility in O(N) time.